# Why is there a "Conditional/Unconditional" setting for command blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When I was making a Zombie Horse Trap (Zombie equivalent of Skeleton Trap) using command blocks, one command block was not doing it's job. I tried clicking the "Unconditional" button to make it "conditional", and it had no effect on the system at all.

**Does this button even have a point?**

If it does, please explain it's purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Gamepedia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_Block#Modification):

> "Conditional": The command block should only execute its command if the command block behind it executed successfully
>
> "Unconditional": The command block should ignore the block behind it

Behind it means the side opposite from the direction the command block is facing.

This differs from chain command blocks because:

> "Chain blocks are green. These execute only after the command block pointing to it is processed. This differs from the Conditional option in that it detects what is pointing to it, instead of simply behind it. The command blocks pointing to it also need not be chain blocks themselves to trigger the chain."

-Gamepedia

I hope this helped. Good luck!

Comment: Also from Gamepedia,  "Chain blocks are green. These execute only after the command block pointing to it is processed. This differs from the Conditional option in that it detects what is pointing to it, instead of simply behind it. The command blocks pointing to it also need not be chain blocks themselves to trigger the chain."

Comment: Yes, but what is the difference between an |impulse|conditional|always active| command block and a |chain|unconditional|always acitve| command block, apart from colour?

Comment: Impluse command blocks are the same as the old ones. Chain will trigger the block it's pointing to. Repeat will execute once per tick (To get rid of clocks). Always active will execute every tick (For making impluse cimmand blocks that are always active). Needs redstone, self explanatory, was the default for the old command blocks.

Comment: I tried the |impulse|conditional|always active| command block and a chain command block and they had the same effect

Comment: You must be doing something wrong.

Comment: How does it define whether the command "behind it" succeeded? I doubt it merely means that it didn't have a syntax error, so what commands distinguish success and failure beyond syntax?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that is correct. The reason for this is so that you can make your redstone/command block builds more compact and it makes it easier to fit the command blocks together.

Comment: That's not correct, please delete this answer .

Comment: His comment makes perfect sense. Making command block arrays more compact is the main idea of chain/conditional impulse command blocks. What has become the discussion here is the difference between |impulse|conditional|always active| and |chain|unconditional|always active| blocks

Comment: I will admit that it is designed to make builds more compact but the main reason is that they do different things.